# How to find out more on error in merge replication on mssql server?

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

How to find out more on error in merge replication on mssql server?

Error that we are getting is:

```
Error messages:
Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 8114)
Get help: http://help/8114
```

This kind of error is not so descriptive so we don't know where to look next. Does anybody know where to look on more descriptive error then this.

We have all objects in replication